# blender rendering question

Tags: rendering, blender

I need to render a 3d model that have been implement uv map in blender.
When I press the render button it renders with normal blender material.
But I need to render it with uv map textures.
please help me.

Comment: Dude, I wish I had a better forum to point you at, I've used myself and think it's a wonderful tool for doing 3d models, but I know they are going to boot this question for not being Programming related.

Comment: Superuser: ewok.adventure is the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clicking the `TexFace` button in the material settings. This should fix your problem.

More information about applying a UV map in Blender is available [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Manual/Textures/UV/Applying_an_Image).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new material for the object, and in the texture panel of that material, add the image you have uv-mapped to an image texture.  Then back on the main material panel, click on Map Input on the far right.  Select the UV button.  This will tell Blender to put the texture on the UV map coordinates.  Now when you render it should show up.